# update SQL contents with hyperlink of other SQL entries by using str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, str-replace

I am working on a dictionary type SQL table. Once I have it completed I have PHP script prepared to update the text with a html hyperlink tag. The script works fine now. However, some of the dictionary entries are phrases and include several words and so the content wont have the proper link associated with them. For example, if I ran the script I currently have it would explode the entire definition and link heart and attack separately. While I wish to have the phrase "heart attack" linked.

WORD: myocardial infarction
DEFINITION: Heart attack
Any suggestions on how to do this?
This is my current script that works.

```
$def = $original['def'];
$explode_string = explode(" ",$def);
$explode_count = count($explode_string);
$compare_count = 0;
if($explode_count>0)
{
    while($compare_count<=$explode_count)
    {
        $sql="SELECT word
             FROM dictionary
             WHERE word='{$explode_string[$compare_count]}'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if(! $result )
        {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row)
        {
            if($explode_string[$compare_count]!="{$original['word']}")
            {
            $replace="<a href=\'http://www.medicresource.com/medicaldictionary/search.php?word=".$explode_string[$compare_count]."\'>{$explode_string[$compare_count]}</a>";
            $def = str_replace($explode_string[$compare_count], $replace, $def);
            }

        }
        ++$compare_count;
    }
}
$update_sql = "UPDATE dictionary SET def='$def' WHERE id='{$original['id']}'";
```

Comment: Have you considered MySQL fulltext search functionality.  I have used that in MSSQL and with the ranking, works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that a better approach would be using a foreach

```
$def = "Heart attack";
$explode_string = explode(" ",$def);
$explode_count = count($explode_string);

if($explode_count>0)
{
    foreach($explode_string as $word)
    {
        $sql="SELECT word
             FROM dictionary
             WHERE word='" . $word . "'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if(! $result )
        {
          //die will kill the script
          echo('Could not get data from query : ' . $sql . " error: " . mysql_error());
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row)
        {
            $replace="<a href=\'http://www.medicresource.com/medicaldictionary/search.php?word=". $word ."\'>" . $word ."</a>";
            $def = str_replace($word, $replace, $def);
        }
    }
}
$update_sql = "UPDATE dictionary SET def='$def' WHERE id='" . $original['id'] . "'";
```